How to play ROS2 bag without losing messages using executors in C++?
How can I play back a ROS2 bag inside  C++ application in such a way that down stream nodes don't get overrun and drop messages? All of the nodes are instantiated within a single C++ application. One of the nodes is a rosbag2 recorder node which should record all published messages.

The following code snippet is for Jazzy/Rolling (won't work on earlier ROS2 versions due to missing rosbag2 features). The trick is to

use simulator time throughout, published by the player
use intra-process communications
play the first message to get the clock published, then seek back
have a worker node that can be queried to see when it has been subscribed to

Here's the code:
rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor exec;

// first the player node which does *not* get added to the executor
rclcpp::NodeOptions player_options;
player_options.parameter_overrides(
    {Parameter("storage.uri", name_of_bag_file),
     Parameter("play.clock_publish_on_topic_publish", true),
     Parameter("play.start_paused", true), Parameter("play.rate", 1.0),
     Parameter("play.disable_keyboard_controls", true)});
player_options.use_intra_process_comms(true);
auto player_node = std::make_shared<rosbag2_transport::Player>(
     "rosbag_player", player_options);

// then the recorder node
rclcpp::NodeOptions recorder_options;
  recorder_options.parameter_overrides(
    {Parameter("use_sim_time", true),
     Parameter("storage.uri", name_of_out_bag),
     Parameter("record.disable_keyboard_controls", true),
     Parameter("record.topics", topics)});
recorder_options.use_intra_process_comms(true);
recorder_node = std::make_shared<rosbag2_transport::Recorder>(
    "rosbag_recorder", recorder_options);
exec.add_node(recorder_node);

// now the custom worker node which does the processing
rclcpp::NodeOptions worker_options;
worker_options.parameter_overrides({Parameter("use_sim_time", true)});
worker_options.use_intra_process_comms(true);

// play the first message in the bag such that the
// clock topic is published. Run the executor until
// the custom worker node has been subscribed to

 if (player_node->play_next() && rclcpp::ok()) {
    while (rclcpp::ok() && !worker_node->isSubscribed()) {
      exec.spin_some();
    }
  }
// seek back and start playing the bag from the beginning
player_node->seek(0);
// this is the main loop where the playback + processing happens
while (player_node->play_next() && rclcpp::ok()) {
   exec.spin_some();
}
exec.spin_some(); // for processing the last message
exec.spin_some(); // for recording the last message
```

